# Pull request on github - showing commits rebased from master

Tags: git, github

I'm working with a team and we're doing feature branches and pull requests.

I created a branch, worked on it a bit while also doing little work on master.

Then, I rebased the branch against master. Now I want to do a pull request.

However, in GitHub, the pull request shows all the commits that happened between when I first made the branch and now - the commits I did on this feature branch, and the commits that are on master that happened in between.

This is noisy clutter - am I doing something wrong? I'd like the pull request to just show the commits that I've made, since the other commits are already on both master and on my branch, no difference.

The only suggestion I see is making another branch based on the latest upstream master and cherry picking commits from my branch onto it.

Answer (score 15):

I used to have the same problem:

If we have `foo` branch, branched from `master`, which is already pushed into `origin`, and on both branches changes were made, then after merging/rebasing I was getting changes from `master` in Pull Request's diff.

I solved it by executing `git fetch` first, updating my local `master` branch, changing local branch to `foo` and then executing commands:

`git rebase master`

`git push -f origin foo:foo`

This is forcing remote branch and then PR's diff contains only proper changes, exactly as the branch would be created based on recent `master`.

Comment: I get 'everything up to date' nothing changes

Comment: Did you pull from `origin/master` first? Did you use force when pushing `foo` to remote?

Comment: I think I forgot to force push, I solved it by changing the 'base' branch on my PR to any branch other than master and then changing it back

Answer (score 4):

You must have done something wrong. As a result of the rebase, you should have only the unique revisions following the last commit in master, and your branch should be ready for a fast-forward.

I did a quick test now, and of course, the pull request shows only the unique revisions as expected. There should be no noisy clutter, and no need to cherry pick. It seems something is wrong with your branches.

Try to rebase again. If you rebased correctly earlier, this should be a NO-OP now. Checkout your branch, and try to rebase again on top of master, like this:

```
git checkout yourbranch
git rebase master
```

This should print `Current branch will-have-rebased is up to date.`, and after you push the branch to GitHub, you should be able to create a pull request where only the unique commits show up. I don't see why not.

**Important:** keep in mind that if you had pushed your branch *before* rebasing, then Git will refuse to push again *after* rebasing. This is because in general you should not rewrite the history of public branches, and all guides on rebasing explain this point. If you want to push the branch anyway, rewriting its history on github, add the `--force` flag.

Comment: That does work as specified, but then I can't push the branch. The answer is because I'd already pushed once before.

Comment: @HsiuDai You can't push again because there is nothing to push, or because Git refuses to rewrite the history of the branch? Can you post the URL of your repo and the name of the branch?

Comment: Private repo I'm afraid, can't give it out. But it's because git refuses to rewrite history, since after the rebase the SHAs are all different now.

Comment: @HsiuDai You can push back using `--force`, see the last paragraph I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, closing the PR and opening a new one with the same branch did the trick.