# Git pull request to upstream contains commits from previous merged pull requests

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Problem: every new pull request that I submit to upstream contains the commits from my previous pull requests that were already merged into upstream. Note that I'm not talking about merge commits.

Workflow/example:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git checkout -b new-feature1
# make changes
git commit -am "comment1"
git push
# create the pull request, it gets merged. Now start on another feature
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git checkout -b new-feature2
# make changes
git add changedfile.py
git commit -m "comment2"
git push
# create the pull request for new-feature2.
# Now the commit history of that PR includes the commits made for new-feature1.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Not sure if it's related, but perhaps worth mentioning that I'm working on multiple branches at the same time which contain unstaged changes. So in the above example, at the time of creating branch `new-feature2`, I have other branches with unstaged changes / newly created files.

Additional info based on comments:

- This doesn't happen with just one PR, it happened structurally, with every new PR including the commit history of all previous PRs
- The base & compare branches are the correct ones
- The changed files the PR shows are the correct ones -- it's just the commit history that's off.

More additional info: here's a snip of the actual git log of upstream/master:
[image: Git log snip]
The author is me for each of these commits, i.e. these are after the PR merges. The first two are fine. The bullet points in the second commit were individual commits I made. **Question:** So does this mean the repo maintainer did a "squash & merge" of the PR?

In the final commit in the screenshot the problem appears. All the previous commits are repeated, in addition to the actual "new" commit.

---

Okay, so I might have an idea what happened. Should there be a `git push` in between `git merge upstream/master` and `git checkout -b new-feature2`? Otherwise the commit created by the merge (which I guess then also includes the commits from the PR, since I did not merge the PR branch locally) will be included in the new branch?

Comment: Looks like your commands sequence is ok. After doing `git merge upstream/master` for second time, did you get the changes/commits of `new-feature1` into master?

Comment: As far as I can tell from `git log`, yes those changes got into master.

Comment: Ok. Then `feature-1` branch's commits should not appear in `feature-2` Pull req! Can you repeat the process and check if it is ok or not? Make sure your `base..compare` branches are alright.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought...can't easily repeat the process, because it will require the upstream repo maintainer to merge my PRs. Right now I don't want to do that since every subsequent PR contains ever longer commit history, also creating double entries in git log. I double checked the base&compare branches were correct yes. I guess I'll delete the fork and recreate it to start with a clean slate.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the whole procedure. You can create a new branch (say, `feature-3`) from your `local/master`. Then do changes, create a new PR and check. Finally, delete your remote `feature-3` branch then the PR will be removed automatically.

Comment: Ah, right. Well, before creating this post I had created 4 or 5 PRs, and every next one contained the commits from all previous ones. So it's not just one PR for which this happened -- it's something structural.

Comment: When your pull requests are merged, are they squashed?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how can I find this out? I see "<repo maintainer> merged commit <commit ID>". And "pull request successfully merged and closed". Btw maybe also worth mentioning: the changed files the PR shows are the correct ones -- it's just the commit history that's off.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen updated the post

Comment: A squash is history rewriting, if you still keep the old, unsquashed, commits around and then later try to push it will look like you're attempting the changes again. This may or may not introduce the same merge conflicts yet again, depending on how git identifies similar changes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks. I don't keep the old unsquashed commits in master. The way I merge the branch with master is the fetch/merge I described in the post. So that should merge the squased commits. But maybe the issue is the question I asked in the updated post below the horizontal ruler?

Comment: @Matt -- did you ever figure this out?  I'm experiencing the same issue: every PR I submit to upstream (from a branch in my forked repo) contains old commits that were already previously merged into upstream.  Not a huge issue (since, as you mentioned the PR shows the correct 'changed files') but I'd love to figure out what's causing it. Thanks in advance for any feedback you may have.

Comment: @KimBrandl hmm sorry don't recall exactly, it's a while ago. I think I switched to using rebase instead of merge commits.

Comment: @Matt - thanks for the update. I've been thinking about switching to rebase as well, perhaps I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I solved this by following this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30998522/2475433