# Previously merged commits keep appearing on new Pull Requests

Tags: git, github

I am having difficulty understanding why some previously merged commits keep appearing in pull requests.

We have a master branch and then an integration one against which we develop against via feature branch pull requests - so git flow type workflow.

I currently have an open PR like so:

[image]

But the first few commits on this, were already merged in an earlier PR:

[image]

I dont get why this is happening, can someone explain?

Comment: You rebased/squashed when you merged in GitHub but you pulled/merged locally. Rebase your changes on top of origin/master and see if that fixes it (run `git rebase -i origin/master` and then `git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD`)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - that initially worked for me, so after performing those commands, I then just end up with only the new commits I expect to see. After merging that PR however, if I attempt to raise a further one just to check I see no diffs, I am still seeing the same two previously merged commits appearing. I am really confused now

Comment: Reset your base branch (master in your case) too, `git checkout master && reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: If anyone wants to take the comment and make it a full answer feel free by the way - I'm on mobile and typing is hard

Comment: There are a bunch of similar questions, e.g., [Pull request on github - showing commits rebased from master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18323665/1256452). I don't really have time right now to find the right duplicate(s), perhaps someone else will...

Comment: The short version of all of this, though, is that merging in Git (and hence PRs on GitHub) works by *commit*, not by *branch name:* the branch names just find the most recent commit, and then each commit locates an earlier commit (or for a merge commit, two or more earlier commits). So you need your *commits* to be *independent*, not dependent on earlier commits. Unfortunately GitHub do not show the *commit graph* and it's the *graph* that determines these dependencies.